# How to remove reference link (__r field) between objects?

Tags: apex, field-update, upsert, reference

I am trying to find a way to unlink reference between two objects.

We have an object of Academic_Institution__c and Previous_Academic_Institution__c. If "CEEB_Code__c" exist Academic Institurion is created, and Previous Academic Institution is created with reference assigned to Academic Institution.

If we get a feed whith the same Previous_Academic_Institution__c, but the CEEB_Code__c empty, I want to remove the reference between Previous_Academic_Institution__c and Academic_Institution__c. I thought it is just a matter of assigning NULL to Academic_Institution__r, but it does not work:

```
   Previous_Academic_Institution__c prevAcadInst =  new Previous_Academic_Institution__c(
                                    Name = collegeName,
                                    PAC_ID__c = getField(rows.get(i), headerMap, 'custom_field_usc_id').replace('-', '') + ':' + collegeName,
                                    Application__r = new Opportunity(Application_Client_Id__c = appId),
                                    CEEB_Code__c = ceebCode,
                                    Academic_Institution__r = String.isNotEmpty(ceebCode) ? new Academic_Institution__c(CEEB_Code__c = ceebCode):null
                                );
```

Here are the logs. I can see that when I am assigning NULL to __r field, then it does not get included for the upsert. How should I remove that link?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the actual lookup field value itself (the __c) instead. We always use __r strictly for navigating relationships and using External Id values, and __c for creating, updating, or removing relationships.

This is one of those rare situations where a ternary operator isn't going to cut it, because you need to update either the __r or __c depending on which branch you need to take:

```
if(String.isNotEmpty(ceebCode)) {
    prevAcadInst.Academic_Institution__r = new Academic_Institution__c(CEEB_Code__c = ceebCode);
} else {
    prevAcadInst.Academic_Institution__c = null;
}
```